# How to format-number without separators

Tags: xslt

I would like to format numbers so that always have 4 digits, but no decimal separators. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

- 0 -> 0000
- 2.5 -> 0250
- 10 -> 1000
- 6.75 -> 0675

I have tried to use the *format-number* function, but with no success. Any tips on how to do it in XSLT 2.0/3.0?

Comment: Show us what you tried and we can explain your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should multiply by 100 and format using the picture '0000'...

**XML Input**

```
<tests>
    <test>0</test>
    <test>2.5</test>
    <test>10</test>
    <test>6.75</test>
</tests>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(xs:double(.) * 100,'0000')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<tests>
   <test>0000</test>
   <test>0250</test>
   <test>1000</test>
   <test>0675</test>
</tests>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfQ/1

Not sure what you want to happen if you get a value larger than 99.99 though.

Comment: Probably safer to use xs:double. These values are atypical in that the fractional part is always a multiple of one quarter, so xs:float probably gives an exact representation.